# SFML RenderWindow taking inconsistent time to display

Tags: c++, sfml

I started a project a few days ago to get to grips with SFML. When I was working on it then, the main sf::RenderWindow constructor would be called instantly. Now that I've come back to the project, it's taking up to 42 seconds in Debug mode to continue beyond the sf::RenderWindow constructor function.

So whenever I run the console appears and 40 seconds later the RenderWindow will appear.

It can't be my computer specifications as I have a very high end PC.

Here's the code in my main function:

```
int main()
    {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(960, 640), "proj v0.0.1"); 

    while (window.isOpen())
    {

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        window.display();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm honestly just very confused as to why there's such a long delay and it's making testing new features very difficult.

Comment: Any chance you're using Visual Studio and the during the debug session it downloaded the debug symbols for system files once again since there's been an update or the local files are damage? Did you verify your HDD/SSD are fine? There's nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: I wasn't downloading debug symbols before but I'm doing so now cause it seems like a good thing to have sorted out.

That being said, I'm currently checking to see if it's a problem with my HDD/SSD by changing the partition I'm working in.

Comment: If you have just one drive, changing partitions won't help much. Run some diagnostic tool like HD Tune.