# SFML RenderWindow taking a long time to open a window

Tags: c++, sfml

I know this is essentially a duplicate, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988505/sfml-renderwindow-taking-inconsistent-time-to-display) wasn't ever answered. I'd like to mention that I have [followed the tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php) for using SFML along with Visual Studio, and I'm running a 64-bit project with 64-bit SFML. The window loaded instantly a few times, and now consistently takes 40 seconds to open on new builds/debugs. I also have the downloading of debug symbols off. My graphics drivers are up to date and my HDD is fine. This is the code:

```
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");//This one
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

Everything runs at normal speed, except for RenderWindow, which again, takes exactly 40 seconds every time. Does anyone know how I could fix this? I've been having this issue for a few weeks now.

e: Could it be my CPU? It's not the best but I can still run most games just fine as I have a 1050ti. My current CPU is an i5-2500k, although I believe I got the same issue on an A10-5800k.

Comment: That is definitely not normal. Have you tried running the binary from outside Visual Studio. Also maybe try building the binary again from scratch

Comment: It was working yesterday after changing nothing and now it's broke again. I'll try to clean everything again I guess.

Comment: Yeah, can't get it to work? Would reinstalling windows do anything? I've reinstalled visual studio twice already

Comment: @Chachmu Running the binary without visual studio didn't change anything, and the program ran earlier today and isn't anymore. Is there any way that having my computer on for an hour or longer just prevents it from working? If I can't figure out to fix it I'll either end up giving up or reinstalling windows

Comment: I don't think reinstalling windows will help in the long run. This is probably some sort of issue with the configuration of visual studio or SFM but I'm not really sure what exactly is causing it

Comment: I figured it might be something with my windows because a fresh install of both visual studio and SFML leads to the same outcome. I guess I could just give up on SFML and try another multimedia library, but I like SFML's documentation and structure. I also don't want to use OpenGL outright because I'm trying to make a fairly simple program as a learning experience, and the graphics aren't the main importance. Thanks for all the advice so far, I'll update if I figure anything out

Comment: @Chachmu Also at this point really all I can do is either stop trying this or reinstall windows, so if there is any chance it could fix it I'm willing to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Before you resort to the solution below, try updating your keyboards firmware! You're most likely using a Corsair keyboard, so download Corsair's [iCue](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/icue) and update your keyboard drivers. This will most likely fix these issues. If it didn't work, then try the following:

Since OP didn't reply any further, I tried to find a workaround myself, as this issue still exists in 2020. This workaround requires you to compile the libraries yourself. So download the source code and change the following:

- In `WindowImpl.cpp`, navigate to the function `WindowImp::WindowImp` and comment out the whole function body.
- In `WindowImpl.cpp`, navigate to `WindowImp::popEvent` and comment out the call to `processJoystickEvents`

As long as you don't use the Joystick part of SFML this should work without issues.

Comment: I also forwarded this to the SFML development team, so hopefully they can find a less hacky workaround

Comment: Ended up here experiencing this issue with an implementation of SFML for RUST. RenderWindow was taking about 5s-10s to launch all of a sudden after a restart. Oddly another restart was all that was required in order to fix my issue. Also worth noting that I do have iCUE installed for my K95.

Answer (score 2):

An contributor on the SFML discord helped me source the issue by going through and showing me how to look through the callstack, and it turned out that the freeze was when polling for dx input, and after a little bit of experimenting we figured out my k55 keyboard was to blame. I'll try to find a fix later tonight, but in short term situations unplugging it makes everything work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same keyboard (Corsair K55). The problem for me was Corsair's iCue software, and quitting it entirely fixed the problem for me without having to unplug my keyboard.