# SFML RenderWindow takes time to open

Tags: c++, sfml

This post is a duplicate as the two other posts on this subject ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988505/sfml-renderwindow-taking-inconsistent-time-to-display), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53017551/sfml-renderwindow-taking-a-long-time-to-open-a-window)) were not answered. When running this code:

```
#include <SFML\System.hpp>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML\Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event evnt;
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt))
        {
            switch (evnt.type)
            {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The console appears immediately, but the RenderWindow won't until around 40 seconds later. On the [second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53017551/sfml-renderwindow-taking-a-long-time-to-open-a-window), the op answered himself saying the problem was caused by his k55 keyboard so I tried unplugging my own and running the program and it worked. I don't feel like buying a new keyboard... Can anyone help me?
(This is my first post btw. Did I do good? I hope it won't get ignored)

Comment: Does this k55 keyboard come with a special driver? If so, what if you uninstall that driver!? Also, is your SFML app the only thing affected by the issue!?

Comment: The keyboard comes with a software (iCue) to control macros and rgb lighting. I can still use the keyboard without the software but I need it to control my mouse's DPI. It has never caused a problem before.
Edit: I tried making it so the software doesn't even detect the keyboard but the problem persists.